# Prevent other windows from "overriding" hotkeys with the windowsAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to learn the basics of the windows API by making a program that, when the PRINTSCREEN button is pressed, will save a .jpeg and instantly upload it to imgur. Currently, while I'm playing most games or just browsing the desktop, this program works fine.

Some games, however, seem to block my ability to use this hotkey. (Dark Souls 2 specifically does this.) I currently use

```
RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, 0, VK_SNAPSHOT)
```

to assign the button to my program. However, when some games are running, neither the above RegisterHotKey nor the below GetAsyncKeyState work when the key is pressed.

```
GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SNAPSHOT)
```

(I don't want to use GetAsyncKeyState due to the fact that it will keep bugging the windows API and make the program unnecessarily slow, it was just for test.)

Does anyone know of a way to stop this from happening?

(and, on an unrelated note: If it is a simple task, how would I take a screenshot spanning multiple monitor(s)? Mine currently works on only my primary monitor...)

Comment: I'm on windows 7. But if you know how to solve this on other versions of windows as well, it would be greatly appreciated! I'm trying to learn as much as I can at once.

Comment: I think you can get a screenshot spanning multiple monitors with `Ctrl-PrtScn`.

Comment: As a remote possibility, you can try using `GlobalAddAtom` for the `id` for `RegisterHotKey`. See the last paragraph in the Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ooga, I know that you can get one like that, but how do you make a corresponding call from the windows API? That's the hard part :) I'll try the `GlobalAddAtom` now though!

Comment: `GlobalAddAtom` isn't something you can pass into the `RegisterHotKey` function as an `id`

Comment: You didn't mention that you knew about `Ctrl-PrtScn` and I don't see what's so difficult about passing `MOD_CONTROL` as the third parameter to `RegisterHotKey`. And if isn't possible to use `GlobalAddAtom` in this context, why is it mentioned in the documenation? But it probably won't solve your problem anyway.

Comment: AH! I misread you. And I think we're thinking about different things-- when I say I use the `printscreen` button, I'm calling my own function that takes a screenshot. I currently actually have it bound to `alt-shift-q` on my own computer. So the default / actual implementation of the `printscreen` button is works independently of my program. And I misread the definition of `GlobalAddAtom` -- I could now get it to work, but it doesn't change the failure of the program. I just want to know how to stop other programs from overriding mine, so that friends can use it simply with `printscreen`.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding, actually. Apparently `CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL)` will return an `HDC` for multiple monitors.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is using [raw input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for its keyboard mapping, then the keyboard processing code bypasses the hotkey checker.  I personally have no idea if Dark Souls does this or not, but I am familiar with the Windows kernel code that does keyboard processing.

Comment: That doesn't explain the problem with GetAsyncKeyState().  It is a multi-player game.  They invariably have PunkBuster-style anti-cheats built in so that a few cheaters don't ruin the game for everybody else.

Comment: So it's likely "impossible" or infeasible to get the keyboard input in the manner I want?

Comment: @HansPassant I'd have to double-check the source; IIRC GetAsyncKeyState can be bypassed as well with raw input.

Comment: @user2899162 Yes, if applications intercept the keyboard input stream at a sufficiently low level, higher-level keyboard processing (hotkeys, window messages, etc.) will not be done.  Therefore, it's not always possible to perform the task you're asking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that GetAsyncKeyState() actually queries the keyboard driver, so it wouldn't be bypassed by raw input. But an app can acquire the keyboard in an exclusive mode, which will prevent any other applications from receiving keyboard input.