# How to simulate a hardware key press by using SendMessage() intead of SendInput()?

Tags: c, winapi, sendmessage, keyboard-hook, sendinput

I have been trying to screen capture a game that blocks the Windows GDI API (possibly via API hooking) and hence I cannot use the good old `BitBlt()` for capturing the screen, unfortunately. Whenever I call `BitBlt` , it fails with an error code: 126 (`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`), which is very weird!

I tried simulating the print screen key on the keyboard using the preferred API `SendInput()` to send `VK_SNAPSHOT` key events to Windows, and **it can capture the screen to the clipboard successfully**, *but only when the game is not running*.

```
INPUT inputs[2];
memset(inputs, 0x00, sizeof(INPUT) * 2);
// Key Press
inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_SNAPSHOT;
inputs[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;

// Key release
inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_SNAPSHOT;
inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

I understand the reason for this behaviour might be because the game (closed source software) has installed a low level keyboard hook via `SetWindowHookEx()` and is trapping the `VK_SNAPSHOT` and is able to distinguish the injected keystroke via checking the `flags` for `LLKHF_INJECTED`, and is trapping such injected `VK_SNAPSHOT` keys by making it skip the chain and it doesn't get passed on to Windows.

**But**, the game application *generously* allows the **hardware** presses to be interpreted by Windows, and I can take a screenshot by pressing the **hardware** <kbd>PrntSc</kbd> (print screen) key on the physical keyboard!

Now, I am assuming that there is a window inside Windows (possibly the desktop window?) that can directly accept the print screen keystroke whether virtual or hardware. I could be wrong, please do correct me.

So, I was thinking of using the Windows API `SendMessage()` to send `VK_SNAPSHOT` events to the desktop window, but unfortunately it is not working, neither when the game is running, nor in normal circumstances in which `VK_SNAPSHOT` sent by `SendInput()` works fine.

This is how I am using `SendMessage()`:

```
/* Key Press */
SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SNAPSHOT, 0) // Is lParam = 0, a problem here?
/* Key Release */ 
SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow()), WM_KEYUP, VK_SNAPSHOT, 0)
```

Coding language: **C** , Environment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, Windows 10 or Windows 11.

Please do consider all this and help me out! Every help, comment and answer will be appreciated! Please understand that everything is for fair use, and the game manufacturer has no problem in taking screen captures, and I don't know why they are blocking this.

Other methods that show me the way in taking screen captures will help me a lot!

Comment: Use [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture).

Comment: @IInspectable Thankyou for the suggestion :) I am coding everything in C , forgot to mention that :( Also, another friend of mine told, that the game hooks directX methods for capture as well :(

Comment: @VivekanandV - You can use Windows.Graphics.Capture from C, it's a WinRT API, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436144/using-winrt-from-c

Comment: @SimonMourier Thankyou for the suggestion, +1, I will look into that :) , but it seems deeply involved and deserves a good amount of research :) , and the syntax is difficult to get used to :(

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the game is simply blocking the VK_SNAPSHOT message with a window hook?  If that's the case, you could have a background process that has its own hotkey (e.g. CTRL+ALT+F6) registered via [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey). Then when your code gets notified of the keypress, you can run your screen scrape code.

Comment: @selbie +1 for the comment :) Yes the hardware print screen successfully works!, but VK_SNAPSHOT is trapped via, I believe a low level keyboard hook. Can you please clarify Ctrl+Alt+F6 and RegisterHotKey :)

Comment: @selbie The game application somehow blocks ```BitBlt``` WINAPI. When the game is running, and I call ```BitBlt``` , I get a weird error code of: 126 from GetLastError()

Comment: I found a very similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819698/prevent-other-windows-from-overriding-hotkeys-with-the-windowsapi  To verify it, you can use the `RegisterHotKey` to make your own screenshot tool to try to take a screenshot.